# Desync scroll in VS Live Share

Tags: visual-studio-code

My friends and i work on code(`c++`) using `VSCode`.

When he scroll down, my screen starts lagging and keeps dragging me towards his position. Same happens to him, if i try to scroll. I want to completely disable scroll sync when we work on one code.

How to disable scroll sync? Where can i find in VSCode?

I have tried to find something on the internet, but nothing and i need to disable this. I dont know exact name, but i think its scroll sync. I use 1.54.2 version.

Comment: You can explicitly stop following someone by clicking the pin icon again or hitting Ctrl+Alt+F / Cmd+Alt+F. for Client or Guest

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ctrl+Alt+F works, as well as there is an icon in the top right hand side of VSCode, a thumbnail that turns on/off follow participant.